# How to change audio frequency?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, bitrate, resampling

I want to change the frequency of an audio file. Meaning: the whole file should sound (say) one octave higher or lower. How to do it? Using `ffmpeg` or other command line open source tool would be preferable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -af 'asetrate=44100*1/2,atempo=2/1' <output>
```

Here, 1/2 is the pitch factor. See the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1076762/48078) for more details.

---

If you need a GUI, use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), it's a free, open source, cross platform audio editing tool.

> Features: Change the pitch without altering the tempo, or vice-versa.

---

As an alternative, try [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). Something like that:

```
sox <infile> <outfile> pitch <shift>
```

where  gives the pitch shift as positive or negative ‘cents’ (i.e. 100ths of a semitone). There are 12 semitones to an octave, so that would mean ±`1200` as a parameter.

Comment: awesome... sox is just what i need!

Comment: Does method using ffmpeg change the duration of the audio?

Comment: @mrgloom No, it should not.

Comment: After using `ffmpeg -i man.wav -af asetrate=48000*0.75,aresample=48000 man_pitch_down.wav` I see by `ffmpeg -i` original wav `Duration: 00:00:01.95, bitrate: 3080 kb/s` and modified wav `Duration: 00:00:02.60, bitrate: 1536 kb/s`. As I understand `Duration` is length in seconds.

Comment: I have tried this solution (https://superuser.com/a/1076762/213959) and it produce audios with same length  (looking at `Duration` from `ffmpeg -i` output)

Comment: @slhck you are wrong. As mrgloom said your ffmpeg line also changes duration af the audio.

Comment: @slhck It's 100% your example: `ffmpeg -i <input> -af asetrate=44100*0.5,aresample=44100 <output>` where `asetrate` changes sample rate to 22050 AND increases the duration by 2. Then `aresample` upsamples it to 44100 keeping increased duration the same. The [asetrate documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetrate) clearly says `This will result in a change of speed and pitch.`

Comment: @F.Vosnim You're right. This must have changed (note that my answer was posted in 2011) in the meantime. Fixed the post.

Answer (score 15):

Find input audio rate beforehand thus:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

Assuming input audio rate 44,100 Hz, this command will do the job:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af asetrate=44100*3/4,atempo=4/3 output.mp4
```

The factor of 3/4 will change most female and “skinny” (chipmunk) voices into male and “fat” voices. Use 4/3 for the opposite:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af atempo=3/4,asetrate=44100*4/3 output.mp4
```

Notice reversed filter order to prevent signal degradation. Whenever possible, lossless operation should come before lossy operation. I’m not 100% sure whether I’m not making some mistake here from misunderstanding FFmpeg filters.

FFmpeg filter `asetrate` should have a variable named `ir` for input audio rate, in analogy to `iw`×`ih` in some video filters, but I couldn’t find any mention of it in the documentation.

For factors greater than 2 (such as 4/1 or 1/4), you must use multiple `atempo` filters (1/4 = 1/2 * 1/2 or 4/1 = 2/1 * 2/1):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af asetrate=44100*4,atempo=1/2,atempo=1/2 output.mp4
```

I don’t know how to obtain “skinny” male voice and “fat” female voice.

Instead of `-af`, you can write `-filter:audio` or `-filter:a`.

### References

- https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo
- https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetrate

Comment: thank you so much!! worked at first attempt!!

Comment: Is speed changed as well? The speed of speech? Is there a way to increase voice pitch without increasing speech speed?

Answer (score 1):

@slhck answer with **better quality resampler**:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -af 'asetrate=44100*1/2:resampler=soxr:precision=33,atempo=2/1' <output>
```

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Confirmed -- `Option 'resampler' not found`